# What is wrong with my overflow-x and flex-wrap in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, row, overflow

I'm trying to make all the movie poster in the same line but my overflow-x and flex-wrap doesn't seem to work at my App.css. This is my App.css:

```
body {
    background: #141414;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.movie-app>.row {
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    /*prevent the wrapping on the next line*/
}
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "./App.css"
import MovieList from "./components/MovieList"

function App() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([{
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
            "Year": "1977",
            "imdbID": "tt0076759",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00Y2Y3LWE3ZjctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
            "Year": "1980",
            "imdbID": "tt0080684",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00NjZmLTg5NGItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
            "Year": "1983",
            "imdbID": "tt0086190",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00Y2IzLTk1NTMtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
            "Year": "2015",
            "imdbID": "tt2488496",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace",
            "Year": "1999",
            "imdbID": "tt0120915",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRhNjcwNWQtMGJmMi00NmQyLWE2YzItODVmMTdjNWI0ZDA2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith",
            "Year": "2005",
            "imdbID": "tt0121766",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones",
            "Year": "2002",
            "imdbID": "tt0121765",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDAzM2M0Y2UtZjRmZi00MzVlLTg4MjEtOTE3NzU5ZDVlMTU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi",
            "Year": "2017",
            "imdbID": "tt2527336",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ1MzcxNjg4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzgwMjY4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker",
            "Year": "2019",
            "imdbID": "tt2527338",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDljNTQ5ODItZmQwMy00M2ExLTljOTQtZTVjNGE2NTg0NGIxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODkzNTgxMDg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Solo: A Star Wars Story",
            "Year": "2018",
            "imdbID": "tt3778644",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM2NTI3NTc3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzM1OTQyNTM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
    ])
    return ( < div className = "container-fluid movie-app" >
        <
        div className = "row" > <
        MovieList movies = { movies }
        />< /div >


        <
        /div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

This is my MovieList.js:

```
import React from 'react'


const MovieList = (props) => {
        return ( < div > {
                props.movies.map((movie, index) => < div >
                    <
                    img src = { movie.Poster }
                    alt = "movie" / > < /
                    div >
                )
            } < /div>)
        }


        export default MovieList;
```

Comment: Someone already moved your code to the right place, better remove the  "Answer" before you collect more downvotes

Answer (score -1):

This is my App.css:

```
body {
    background: #141414;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.movie-app>.row {
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    /*prevent the wrapping on the next line*/
}
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "./App.css"
import MovieList from "./components/MovieList"

function App() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([{
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
            "Year": "1977",
            "imdbID": "tt0076759",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00Y2Y3LWE3ZjctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
            "Year": "1980",
            "imdbID": "tt0080684",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00NjZmLTg5NGItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
            "Year": "1983",
            "imdbID": "tt0086190",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00Y2IzLTk1NTMtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
            "Year": "2015",
            "imdbID": "tt2488496",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace",
            "Year": "1999",
            "imdbID": "tt0120915",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRhNjcwNWQtMGJmMi00NmQyLWE2YzItODVmMTdjNWI0ZDA2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith",
            "Year": "2005",
            "imdbID": "tt0121766",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones",
            "Year": "2002",
            "imdbID": "tt0121765",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDAzM2M0Y2UtZjRmZi00MzVlLTg4MjEtOTE3NzU5ZDVlMTU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi",
            "Year": "2017",
            "imdbID": "tt2527336",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ1MzcxNjg4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzgwMjY4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker",
            "Year": "2019",
            "imdbID": "tt2527338",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDljNTQ5ODItZmQwMy00M2ExLTljOTQtZTVjNGE2NTg0NGIxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODkzNTgxMDg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Solo: A Star Wars Story",
            "Year": "2018",
            "imdbID": "tt3778644",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM2NTI3NTc3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzM1OTQyNTM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
    ])
    return ( < div className = "container-fluid movie-app" >
        <
        div className = "row" > <
        MovieList movies = { movies }
        />< /div >


        <
        /div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

This is my MovieList.js:

```
import React from 'react'


const MovieList = (props) => {
        return ( < div > {
                props.movies.map((movie, index) => < div >
                    <
                    img src = { movie.Poster }
                    alt = "movie" / > < /
                    div >
                )
            } < /div>)
        }


        export default MovieList;
```